# How to open/close react-bootstrap modal programmatically?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I need to open/close modal like

> $(element).modal('show')

How to do that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What you are looking for is the custom modal trigger, which uses the `OverlayMixin` and allows you to manage the modal's state yourself.  You can control whether the modal is shown using `this.setState({isModalOpen: true})` to achieve the equivalent of what you asked for in your post in the example below. The following code is from the react-bootstrap website (http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals):

```
const CustomModalTrigger = React.createClass({
  mixins: [OverlayMixin],

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      isModalOpen: false
    };
  },

  handleToggle() {
    this.setState({
      isModalOpen: !this.state.isModalOpen
    });
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <Button onClick={this.handleToggle} bsStyle='primary'>Launch</Button>
    );
  },

  // This is called by the `OverlayMixin` when this component
  // is mounted or updated and the return value is appended to the body.
  renderOverlay() {
    if (!this.state.isModalOpen) {
      return <span/>;
    }

    return (
      <Modal bsStyle='primary' title='Modal heading' onRequestHide={this.handleToggle}>
        <div className='modal-body'>
          This modal is controlled by our custom trigger component.
        </div>
        <div className='modal-footer'>
          <Button onClick={this.handleToggle}>Close</Button>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<CustomModalTrigger />, mountNode);
```

**UPDATE (Aug 4, 2015)**

In the newest version of React-Bootstrap, whether a modal is shown or not is controlled by a `show` prop which is passed to the modal.  The `OverlayMixin` is no longer needed to control the modal state.  Controlling the state of the modal is still done via `setState`, in this example via `this.setState({ showModal: true })`.  The following is based off the example on the React-Bootstrap website:

```
const ControlledModalExample = React.createClass({

  getInitialState(){
    return { showModal: false };
  },

  close(){
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  },

  open(){
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.open}>
          Launch modal
        </Button>

        <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <div>Modal content here </div>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Does not work if you need to access a form element in the modal using `refs`

Comment: running into this issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately    "setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains."   I call setState and it doesn't update

Comment: Steve, what is your specific issue?  Perhaps you can post a question with your code and the issue you are having.

Answer (score 12):

Your modal will have a `show` prop and an `onHide` prop to determine when it's displayed. E.g.:

```
<Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
```

The `onHide` function simply changes `showModal` state property. Your modal is shown/hidden based on the parent's state:

```
close(){
  this.setState({ showModal: false });
}
```

If you'd like to close the modal from within the modal itself, you can trigger the `onHide` function defined on the parent via `props`. For example, this is a button somewhere inside the modal closing it:

```
<button type="button" className="close" onClick={this.props.onHide}>
  <span>&times;</span>
</button>
```

[**Here is a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/janklimo/dy34twvk/) simulating this workflow.

Comment: I'd appreciate to hear your reasoning when you downvote.

Comment: this is not a bootstrap modal.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/16j1se1q/1/ this is what a modal looks like. Yours is an example of how to make appear and disappear a div in react which is useful but not for this problem

Answer (score 4):

Open and close react-bootstrap modal programmatically/dynamically from the state:

Here I used the ES6 syntax class component syntax.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './GenericModal.scss';

class GenericModal extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
  super(props, context);

  this.state = {
    showModal: false
  };

  this.open = this.open.bind(this);
  this.close = this.close.bind(this);
}


open() {
  this.setState({showModal: true});
}

close() {
  this.setState({showModal: false});
}

render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <div>I am a Bootstrap Modal</div>
      <Button onClick={this.open}>Show Modal</Button>
      <div>
        <Modal className="modal-container" 
          show={this.state.showModal} 
          onHide={this.close}
          animation={true} 
          bsSize="small">

          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>

          <Modal.Body>
            One of fine body.........
          </Modal.Body>

          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
            <Button bsStyle="primary">Save changes</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>         
        </Modal> 
      </div>
    </div>
  );
 }
}

export default GenericModal;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with React [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). (Included in React 16.8)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const ComponentWithModal = props => {
  const [isModalOpen, setModalStatus] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>I am a Bootstrap Modal</div>
      <Button onClick={() => setModalStatus(true)}>Show Modal</Button>
      <div>
        <Modal
          className="modal-container"
          show={isModalOpen}
          onHide={() => setModalStatus(false)}
        >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>

          <Modal.Body>Modal content here</Modal.Body>

          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={() => setModalStatus(false)}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ComponentWithModal;
```