# Why does calling react setState method not mutate the state immediately?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm reading [Forms](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) section of [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) documentation and just tried this code to demonstrate `onChange` usage ([JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/zilofo/edit?html,js,console,output)).

```
var React= require('react');

var ControlledForm= React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            value: "initial value"
        };
    },

    handleChange: function(event) {
        console.log(this.state.value);
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        console.log(this.state.value);

    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        );
    }
});

React.render(
    <ControlledForm/>,
  document.getElementById('mount')
);
```

When I update the `<input/>` value in the browser, the second `console.log` inside the `handleChange` callback prints the same `value` as the first `console.log`, Why I can't see the result of `this.setState({value: event.target.value})` in the scope of `handleChange` callback?

Comment: If you're using hooks, take a look at [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/1218980).

Comment: React 18 has introduced [automatic batching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71772322/3340702)

Answer (score 725, accepted):

From React's [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> `setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to `setState` and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

If you want a function to be executed after the state change occurs, pass it in as a callback.

```
this.setState({value: event.target.value}, function () {
    console.log(this.state.value);
});
```

Comment: Good answer. The observation that I need to do is be careful to use valueLink. It works good if you not have to format/mask the input.

Comment: You might also want to check out `componentDidUpdate`. It will be called after the state has changed.

Comment: Quick question if i may, i see once we pass the  function which we need as  callback  to setState , i was hoping that  the func would be executed first before render() is called. But i see the order is setState() -> render() -> setStates' callback() . 
is this normal? What if we want to control our render based on the stuff we do in callback ? _shouldComponentUpdate_?

Comment: Changing state of a component will always trigger a re-render unless there is behavior in `shouldComponentUpdate` that specifies otherwise.  What exactly are you trying to do in the callback you're passing to `setState` that you want to occur before the re-render?

Comment: ...why? Could someone justify this?

Comment: How could I add the prevState and props to a setState with callback? Adding a callback to my working setStates with prevStates makes them to stop working.

Comment: @JackHasaKeyboard What I was told was that it's done for performance reasons. The setState is actually completed when there are resources to do so.

Comment: What about `useState` in hooks that doesn't receive immediate change either? We cannot pass the callback.

Comment: What if the callback does not work as you said. mine does not!

Comment: Is this still correct answer for updated react version? I am using this and getting a warning like `Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().`

Answer (score 57):

As mentioned in the React documentation, there is no guarantee of `setState` being fired synchronously, so your `console.log` may return the state prior to it updating.

Michael Parker mentions passing a callback within the `setState`. Another way to handle the logic after state change is via the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method, which is the method recommended in React docs.

> Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for such logic instead.

This is particularly useful when there may be successive `setState`s fired, and you would like to fire the same function after every state change. Rather than adding a callback to each `setState`, you could place the function inside of the `componentDidUpdate`, with specific logic inside if necessary.

```
// example
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.state.value > prevState.value) {
    this.foo();  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

You could try using ES7 async/await. For instance using your example:

```
handleChange: async function(event) {
    console.log(this.state.value);
    await this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    console.log(this.state.value);
}
```

Comment: How is your answer different from the other high quality answer?

Comment: The other answer is with respect to using the callback in setState(). I thought I put this here for those whom a callback use case doesn't apply. For instance, when I faced this problem myself, my use case involved a switch case on the updated state right after setting it. Therefore using async/await was preferred to using a callback.

Comment: will this impact performance if I always use await always when I want to update some state and then wait for it to have updated? And if I put multiple await setStates in a chain one below another, will it render after each setState update? or after the last setState update?

Comment: [`setState` is asynchronous but doesn't return anything](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b43785e151a06c91e4c8b3e6e01b615bdc37e33a/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js#L33-L67), so [`await` will work most of the time but only by chance as it's a race-condition.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45744345/1218980)

Answer (score 14):

Watch out the react lifecycle methods！

- http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/
- https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

I worked for several hours to find out that `getDerivedStateFromProps` will be called after every `setState()`.

Answer (score 11):

Sometime this issue occurs with state.
In case of hooks, you should use `useEffect` hook, As below-

```
const [fruit, setFruit] = useState('');
 
setFruit('Apple');
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Fruit', fruit);
}, [fruit])
```

This saved my day, Hope will help you!!!

Answer (score 4):

Accessing `this.state` after calling the `setState` method is not guaranteed to return the updated status due to the asynchronous nature of `setState`.

To guarantee an update after calling `setState`, there are two solutions you may pursue.

**Solution 1:** As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42602520/5959372) in one of the above answers, put your code in the `componentDidUpdate` method

**Solution 2:** As mentioned in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30783011/5959372) of the above answers, pass your stuff as a callback

```
 this.setState({value: myValue}, function () {
    this.functionThatIsExecutedWhenStateIsUpdated();
});
```

It's important to note that these two solutions are not clearly interchangeable. The one cannot easily solve all the use-cases of the other. As a general rule, if you can, best practice says that solution 1 is preferred. But, there are use-cases where only solution 2 "more effectively" works such as the "update-my-view-and-post-my-data" use case. This use case goes like this:

After adding an item, say, "Add Schedule", I want to **both** add that item to a front-end list and immediately post the just-updated-list to the backend, as demonstrated in the concept below:
[image]

If you dont do either solution, i.e. if you only say this in your code:

```
addToItemArray = () => { 
     this.setState{{ scheduledItemsArray: newObjectListWithMax}}   
     this.postData();
}

<button className="btn btn-secondary btn-block" onClick={this.addToItemArray}>Add Shedule</button>
```

... you will post the list **excluding** the "Delivery to Max" item, because the state wont be updated when you `this.postData()` (again, because its asynchronous).

If you utilise solution 1, you would make a POST after typing in every character in the Schedule Name textbox!

There are other ways aswell to cater for this use-case but solution 2 best conveys the intent when reading the code.

Given the ubiquitous nature of this use case in virtually every web app, the callback technique explained by [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30783011/5959372) is an indispensable piece of code in every developers toolkit.

Answer (score 3):

`async-await` syntax works perfectly for something like the following...

```
changeStateFunction = () => {
  // Some Worker..

  this.setState((prevState) => ({
  year: funcHandleYear(),
  month: funcHandleMonth()
}));

goNextMonth = async () => {
  await this.changeStateFunction();
  const history = createBrowserHistory();
  history.push(`/calendar?year=${this.state.year}&month=${this.state.month}`);
}

goPrevMonth = async () => {
  await this.changeStateFunction();
  const history = createBrowserHistory();
  history.push(`/calendar?year=${this.state.year}&month=${this.state.month}`);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

React bathces different set state calls so that it can determine what is the most optimal strategy for rerendering the website is going to be.

Imagine you have an application where you have a lot of different components. Perhaps, with one button click you are updating the state in multiple components, not just on the current one. In this case, React does not want to just completely isolate and do all those different updates independently.

React wants to figure out if it can stack all these updates together, maybe there is a more optimal way of updating these components so that it is more performant. This is what React is doing behind the scenes. As a result, set state call is asynchronous call.

Answer (score 0):

> Simply putting - this.setState({data: value}) is asynchronous in
>   nature that means it moves out of the Call Stack and only comes back
>   to the Call Stack unless it is resolved.

Please read about Event Loop to have a clear picture about Asynchronous nature in JS and why it takes time to update -

> **https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/javascript-event-loop-explained-4cd26af121d4**

Hence -

```
    this.setState({data:value});
    console.log(this.state.data); // will give undefined or unupdated value
```

as it takes time to update.
To achieve the above process -

```
    this.setState({data:value},function () {
     console.log(this.state.data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are seeing the same value in both console logs is because `setState()` is an asynchronous function. Therefore, the console log after `setState()` is executed before the state is actually updated.

If you want to see the updated value of `this.state.value` in the `handleChange()` callback, you should use the second argument of `setState()`, which is a callback function that is executed once the state is updated. You can modify the `handleChange()` function like this:

```
handleChange: function(event) {
  console.log(this.state.value);
  this.setState({value: event.target.value}, function() {
    console.log(this.state.value);
  });
},
```

This will log the updated value of `this.state.value` in the callback function of `setState()`.

Comment: setState isn't an async function afaik, it just behaves similarly because state updates are batched